# ¿Cómo transformar un JSON a un data.frame?

Tags: json, r

Estoy trabajando con Rstudio y tengo una carpeta con 450 JSON, cuando quiero compilar algunos JSON como Dataframe esta todo bien, pero con algunos JSON me deja el siguiente error

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Este es el [JSON](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DsezCmN8_8iLNCAsLZiRnxTrwnWu6LkD/view?usp=sharing)

El codigo que use es este, los que están bien obtengo 1 observación de x variables

```
JSONList <- rjson::fromJSON(file = "2.json", simplify = F)

DF <- as.data.frame(JSONList$tm)
```

Despues pense en la posibilidad de elegir solo las columnas que necesito

```
    candidatos = list(
"name",
"score",
"tot_sFieldGoalsMade",
"tot_sFieldGoalsAttempted",
"tot_sTwoPointersMade",
"tot_sTwoPointersAttempted",
"tot_sThreePointersMade",
"tot_sThreePointersAttempted",
"tot_sFreeThrowsMade",
"tot_sFreeThrowsAttempted",
"tot_sReboundsDefensive",
"tot_sReboundsOffensive",
"tot_sReboundsTotal",
"tot_sAssists",
"tot_sBlocks",
"tot_sTurnovers",
"tot_sFoulsPersonal",
"tot_sPointsInThePaint",
"tot_sPointsSecondChance",
"tot_sPointsFromTurnovers",
"tot_sBenchPoints",
"tot_sPointsFastBreak",
"tot_sSteals"
)

 ListColum<-map(candidatos, function(x){
    as.data.frame(data$tm$"2"$x)
     } )
```

Pero eso me devuelve una lista de 23 con DF vacíos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `JSON` que diste de ejemplo, no parece una estructura fácilmente trasladable a un `data.frame`, es un árbol con muchos nodos. Por ejemplo, el nodo `tm`, tiene varios datos consistentes con una fila pero también tiene nodos como `coachDetails` que abren otras listas de datos.

Sin embargo, las columnas que has puesto en el ejemplo, si son fácilmente trasladables:

```
candidatos = c(
  "name",
  "score",
  "tot_sFieldGoalsMade",
  "tot_sFieldGoalsAttempted",
  "tot_sTwoPointersMade",
  "tot_sTwoPointersAttempted",
  "tot_sThreePointersMade",
  "tot_sThreePointersAttempted",
  "tot_sFreeThrowsMade",
  "tot_sFreeThrowsAttempted",
  "tot_sReboundsDefensive",
  "tot_sReboundsOffensive",
  "tot_sReboundsTotal",
  "tot_sAssists",
  "tot_sBlocks",
  "tot_sTurnovers",
  "tot_sFoulsPersonal",
  "tot_sPointsInThePaint",
  "tot_sPointsSecondChance",
  "tot_sPointsFromTurnovers",
  "tot_sBenchPoints",
  "tot_sPointsFastBreak",
  "tot_sSteals"
)

df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(JSONList$tm, FUN=function(x) {data.frame(x[candidatos])}))
str(df)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ name                       : chr  "ARGENTINO" "LIBERTAD"
 $ score                      : num  76 77
 $ tot_sFieldGoalsMade        : num  29 31
 $ tot_sFieldGoalsAttempted   : num  60 63
 $ tot_sTwoPointersMade       : num  22 25
 $ tot_sTwoPointersAttempted  : num  42 38
 $ tot_sThreePointersMade     : num  7 6
 $ tot_sThreePointersAttempted: num  18 25
 $ tot_sFreeThrowsMade        : num  11 9
 $ tot_sFreeThrowsAttempted   : num  14 15
 $ tot_sReboundsDefensive     : num  27 26
 $ tot_sReboundsOffensive     : num  6 8
 $ tot_sReboundsTotal         : num  33 34
 $ tot_sAssists               : num  7 8
 $ tot_sBlocks                : num  3 0
 $ tot_sTurnovers             : num  9 8
 $ tot_sFoulsPersonal         : num  14 15
 $ tot_sPointsInThePaint      : num  34 44
 $ tot_sPointsSecondChance    : num  8 9
 $ tot_sPointsFromTurnovers   : num  14 12
 $ tot_sBenchPoints           : num  15 11
 $ tot_sPointsFastBreak       : num  23 5
 $ tot_sSteals                : num  5 6
```